# Tableau Bar Chart Using Multiple Pictures instead of Bar Charts

Tags: bar-chart, data-visualization, tableau-api

I have bar chart in Tableau.

Where to find tutorial on replacing bar chart with certain number of say, pictures of cupcakes in a row (i.e. to tell a more captivating story).

Please guide.

[image]

Comment: IT may well be possible, but it is very bad dataviz practice to do it. Edward Tufte would be turning in his grave were he dead at the very thought.

Comment: @matt_black My management would like this, hence my question

Answer (score 2):

For doing the same.

1. Gather the PNG image for custom shape and place it in Tableau Repository. For reference, 
   Click [here](https://www.interworks.com/blog/ccapitula/2015/01/16/tableau-essentials-formatting-tips-custom-shapes) for the same.
2. Now to replace bar with an image for custom shape. For reference, 
   Click [here](http://www.thedataschool.co.uk/damiana-spadafora/bars-are-boring-use-cute-little-shapes-instead/) for the same.

Below is a link if the shapes doesn't appear instead of bars. Changes to be made in Analysis. For reference, 
Click [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/158328).